# Data protection

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

I am building an Android app which communicates with a mySQL server using php scripts.
I am somewhat concerned that once my app is released people might use the data on my database with tools other than my own app.
How do I make sure that my app it the only one that can communicate with the server?

Thanks!

Comment: can use https connection with credential .....

Comment: Make authentication script for that. Your server will authenticate user then only user can work further. I am pointing out to **SESSION**

Comment: @DheereshSingh Could work, but If someone really wanted to get the data, he could do a NAT to redirect the traffic to a web server of his own that acts as a proxy and logs all requests and responses between the app and the server. (Man-in-the-middle attack)